# using #defined function names as an input to dlsym

Tags: c, dlopen

I have to use dlsym to load a function name from an external library.

But my concern is that he function is defined via a macro #define.

Assuming that dlopen call was successful, will dlsym find the correct symbol using the #defined name in this case?

The following is a header file which includes the #defined function name:

```
#define LogVPrintDebug(context, fmt, args)    \
       (void) LogVPrint(context, kLevel_Debug, fmt, args)

LogErr LogVPrint_(LogContext context, LogLevel level,
    const char* fmt, va_list args) __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

and LogVPrint is the actual funciton.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your problem in text, you should show some code, most importantly *how* you `#define` the name.

Comment: Explain which library are you dynamically loading with `dlopen` and how and why you are using `dlsym` (on which particular symbol). Please *edit your question* to improve it (it is unclear).

Comment: Oh, you mean that the external library was compiled with a macro and you want to use that macro too? Then that's not possible. Macros are not actually part of the of the compiled code, instead the preprocessor *replaces* macros with the actual code, the macros themselves leave no trace in the compiled code.

Comment: ah ok. this is a bit troubling because i have all different kinds of log funcitons such as warningLog, errorLog, criticalLog that are all #defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course `dlsym` *cannot* find a `#define`-d symbol, since the C compiler is starting by its preprocessing phase which is expanding previously `#define`-d macros. So when the code using that name has been compiled, the preprocessed name is used (and only that name occurs in the shared object)

Comment: Thank you. I guess I would have to manually map the names to the expanded function declaration...